# How to check the direction of friction in case of pure rolling

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

I was stuck in a question as follows:

> [image]

Here, I'm not able to understand that how to decide the direction of friction and about which point we should check the torque for the same purpose. Would someone please help me with this problem?

P S: Please apologise for errors, as this is my first post.Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friction occurs where the disk is in contact with the surface. The friction force is applied to the disk at that point and is parallel to the surface. It is in the opposite direction of the velocity of the contact point $v_c$ with respect to the surface.

This allows to compute the torque of the frictional force with respect to A.

Combining the translation speed $v_0$ of the center of the disk with the tangential velocity $\omega R$ with respect to the center gives $v_c = v_0 + \omega R\;$ ($\omega>0$ counterclockwise, $v_0>0$ towards right).

In the text it looks like absolute values for $\omega$ are used.